# Compare two sets of a class without equals

Tags: java, junit, assertj

I have a class Something:

```
public class Something {
   public String a;
   public String b;
}
```

Suppose I can't write equals or compare method in class Something.

My test:

```
Set<Something> aSet;
Set<Something> otherSet;

assertEquals(aSet, otherSet);//Fails because it only compares references of elements and does not perform a deep comparision field by field
```

Is there any way to assert if both sets are equals comparing elements field by field (without writing equals method in Something class)?

Comment: You can use a TreeSet with a custom comparator.

Comment: This SO question also looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204082/is-it-possible-in-java-make-something-like-comparator-but-for-implementing-custo

Comment: Please use only those tags that are really relevant to your question. Your question has **no** relation whatsoever to mocking frameworks!

Comment: Well, what's the point in using a set when you don't have proper equals/hashcode methods in the class? Is there really "something" that adds instances multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try to AssertJ, it provides a way to [compare element field by field recursively](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator--), example:

```
// the Dude class does not override equals
Dude jon = new Dude("Jon", 1.2);
Dude sam = new Dude("Sam", 1.3);
jon.friend = sam;
sam.friend = jon;

Dude jonClone = new Dude("Jon", 1.2);
Dude samClone = new Dude("Sam", 1.3);
jonClone.friend = samClone;
samClone.friend = jonClone;

assertThat(asList(jon, sam)).usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator()
                            .contains(jonClone, samClone);
```

Another possibility is to compare collections using a [specific element comparator](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#custom-comparison-strategy) so `SomethingComparator` in your case, this requires a bit more work than the first option but you have full control of the comparison.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I chose this because is correct and really simple and fluent. It doesn't make sense to add code to classes only for testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hamcrest Library and do

```
assertThat( aSet, both(everyItem(isIn(otherSet))).and(containsInAnyOrder(aSet)));
```

Comment: How would this work without an equals method?

Comment: I agree with @shmosel - I really doubt that this *answers* the question. Those hamcrest matchers ... will call equals() in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar situation when I couldn't implement `equals/hashCode` in the legacy code.

Let me share a solution based on the wrapper pattern. You wrap your legacy class and implement `equals/hashCode` there. In your tests you create a sets of wrapped objects and test it by regular way.

```
public class SomethingTest {
    class SomethingWrapper {
        private final Something value;

        SomethingWrapper(Something value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;

            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            SomethingWrapper that = (SomethingWrapper) o;

            return new EqualsBuilder()
                    .append(value.a, that.value.a)
                    .append(value.b, that.value.b)
                    .isEquals();
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37)
                    .append(value.a)
                    .append(value.b)
                    .toHashCode();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void compareSomethingSetsWithoutEquals() {
        final Set<Something> originalA = new HashSet<>();
        originalA.add(new Something("a1", "b1"));
        originalA.add(new Something("a2", "b2"));

        final Set<Something> originalB = new HashSet<>();
        originalB.add(new Something("a1", "b1"));
        originalB.add(new Something("a2", "b2"));

        final Set<SomethingWrapper> aWrappedSetA =
                originalA.stream().map(SomethingWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        final Set<SomethingWrapper> aWrappedSetB =
                originalB.stream().map(SomethingWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        assertEquals(aWrappedSetA, aWrappedSetB);
    }
}
```