# How to find an intersection between 2 nested collections

Tags: java, java-stream

Say I have 2 nested collections, kind of a collection of multiple OneToMany relations.
For example a `Post` has many `Comments`, a `Comment` can have many `Tags`, sets. So let's just limit to the Post and Comments relation defined as follows as POJOs:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
private static class Post {
    private String title;
    private Set < Comment > comments = new HashSet < > ();


    public Post(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Post addComment(Comment comment) {
        getComments().add(comment);
        return this;
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
private static class Comment {
    private String text;

    public Comment(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Let's create 2 Posts with comments:

```java
Post post1 = new Post("post-1").
addComment(new Comment("com-1")).
addComment(new Comment("com-2"));

Post post2 = new Post("post-2").
addComment(new Comment("com-21")).
addComment(new Comment("com-22")).
addComment(new Comment("com-1")).
addComment(new Comment("com-2"));
```

The question is how to find a collection of comments for the above posts having the same `text` value?
I tried to use `retainAll` but it fails to solve that:

```java
Set <Comment> post1Comments = new HashSet(post1.getComments());
System.out.println("post1 comments before: " + post1Comments);
post1Comments.retainAll(post2.getComments());
System.out.println("post1 comments after: " + post1Comments);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you override `equals` and `hashcode` methods in `Comment` class?

Comment: not at all, I had an idea to add #equals to be able to compare just by Comment#text value.

Comment: the `retainAll()` method returns `boolean` right?

Comment: @Aristotle, right,  true in case if the collection was modified, it is a modification in-place.

Comment: So in order to compare objects, you must `@override` the `equals&hashcode` As the above comments say :) Otherwise, the `retainAll()` method wouldn't be able to find the intersection.

Answer (score 4):

`Set` uses `equals` and `hashcode` methods to compare objects. If you don't override them in your `Comment` class, then it will have those methods inherited from the `java.lang.Object` class. That implementation uses object identity and two objects with the same content in it will be recognized as different entities. You have to correctly override `equals` and `hashcode` methods in your `Comment` class to solve this problem.

Comment: As it was suggested, I think using `equals` and `hashCode` overridden methods and opt for `retainAll` method, I find it more readable than using Stream API. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just add equals and hashCode methods to Comment class. Something like this

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Comment comment = (Comment) o;
        return Objects.equals(text, comment.text);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(text);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`retainAll()` is the standard method to compute the intersection between two collections.

However, any collection method that needs to compare elements for equivalence or for sorting, relies on `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

If you don't provide your own implementations of such methods, the defaults in `Object` will consider two objects equivalent only if they're exactly the same instance, and every time you do `new Comment()` you get a physically new instance, no matter if the comment's text is the same of some other `Comment` object.

In order to do what you want, you should override the `Comment` equivalence methods, using `this.text` as delegates.

In general, that's tricky, cause it forces you to adopt a unique equivalence criterion, which isn't always possible, eg, if you just want to list unique comments that have been made on a post, the above is fine, if you want to know the number of times the same thing has been repeated, you need some other equivalence criteria (eg, adding the author or the timestamp).

There are alternatives to the above.

One is to make computations manually, using streams as [suggested by Hulya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66597619/529286) is a good way to do it (once you've learned about streams), cause it's quick and you can easily take advantage of parallelism (though in this case, you would require `Collections.synchronizedSet()` and maybe the amounts of needed synchronization wouldn't make it so fast).

Another approach is to implement delegates, ie, `new CommentDelegate( originalComment ))`, where each delegate would provide its own flavour of `equals()` and `hashCode()`. Variants of this are possible, eg, you could have a `CustomCommentKey` for each comment and populate a `HashMap` to create a custom-criterion index of comments, the map always contains the intersection of any sets of comments you add to it, since it factorises by key unicity.

Another very clean option is to use collection implementations that are alternatives to those available in the standard Java, where the new implementations accept an `HashingStrategy` interface, having methods like `equals ( o1, o2 )` and `hashCode ( o )`. This, like the existing `Comparator`, allow for comparing objects of a given type against a custom criterion, which is untied from the original type (ie, from `Comment`) and allows for composition. While I've never tried it, [Eclipse has a library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24370280/529286) for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect `text` values of the comments of `post2` to a set. Then you can use the `contains()` method in a filter to find the intersection:

```
Set<Comment> post1Comments = post1.getComments().stream() // check every comment of post1
        .filter( // filter if post2 has the comment with same text value
            comment -> post2.getComments().stream() // get comments of post2
            .map(Comment::getText) // extract text values
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()) // collect text values of post2's comments to a set
            .contains(comment.getText())) // check if the set contains the text value of the comment in the post1
        .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // collect the filtered comments to a set

System.out.println(post1Comments);
```

Output:

```
[com-1, com-2]
```

I added a `toString()` method to `Comment` class to get the output above:

```
public class Comment {
    //...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: The stream chain isn't easy to understand for the beginner, you should spread it over multiple lines and add comments of explanation to each line.

Comment: Sometimes I think I will update if OP has a question. But the format you recommend will bring maximum benefit to everyone. Thanks @zakmck I'll edit soon...

Answer (score 0):

What you could do if you only need to check the content and don't need any ideas corresponding to a post, then you could Stream over the first list, then put a filter to the stream which transforms the second list to a string stream and filters all values that don't exist in both streams, after that map your text back to a post and you're done

```java
List<Post> duplicates = posts1.stream()
                .map(Post::getText)
                .filter(posts2.stream().map(Post::getText).collect(Collectors.toSet())::contains)
                .map(Post::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Maybe it would be more efficient to store the stream of the second list and reference this right there, and also it could be more nicely to read

Comment: This code is correct, but the issue with such kind of approach is that if class would extend with additional fields, developer should add this fields in multiple places.