# HashSet.contains(object) returns false for instance modified after insertion

Tags: java, collections, hashset

According to the [JavaDoc of java.util.HashSet.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) the method does following

> Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e
>   such that **(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))**.

However this does not seem to work for following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashSet<DemoClass> set = new HashSet<DemoClass>();
    DemoClass toInsert = new DemoClass();
    toInsert.v1 = "test1";
    toInsert.v2 = "test2";
    set.add(toInsert);
    toInsert.v1 = null;

    DemoClass toCheck = new DemoClass();
    toCheck.v1 = null;
    toCheck.v2 = "test2";

    System.out.println(set.contains(toCheck));
    System.out.println(toCheck.equals(toInsert));
}

private static class DemoClass {
    String v1;
    String v2;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((v1 == null) ? 0 : v1.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((v2 == null) ? 0 : v2.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        DemoClass other = (DemoClass) obj;
        if (v1 == null) {
            if (other.v1 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!v1.equals(other.v1))
            return false;
        if (v2 == null) {
            if (other.v2 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!v2.equals(other.v2))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

prints out:

> false
>
> true

So although the `equals` method returns `true`, `HashSet.contains()` returns `false`.

I guess this is because I modified the toInsert instance AFTER it was added to the collection.

However this is in no way documented (or at least I wasn't able to find such). Also the documentation referenced above the equals method should be used but it does not seem so.

Comment: You changed the hash, which was remembered by HashSet, hence it can't identify an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HashSet contains problem with custom objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110376/hashset-contains-problem-with-custom-objects)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When an object is stored in a `HashSet` its put in a data structure that's easily (read: efficiently) searchable by the object's `hashCode()`. Modifying an object may change its `hashCode()` (depending on how you implemented it), but does not update its location in the `HashSet`, as the object has no way of knowing its contained in one.

There are a couple of things you can do here:

1. Modify the implementation of `hashCode()` so it isn't affected by the field you're changing. Assuming this field is important to the object's state, and participates in the `equals(Object)` method, this is somewhat of a code smell, and should probably be avoided.
2. Before modifying the object, remove it from the set, and then re-add it once you're done modifying it:

```
Set<DemoClass> mySet = ...;
DemoClass demo = ...;
boolean wasInSet = mySet.remove(demo);
demo.setV1("new v1");
demo.setV2("new v2");
if (wasInSet) {
    set.add(demo);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`HashSet` and `HashMap` use both `hashCode` and `equals` methods to locate an object in their inner structure. `hashCode` is used to find a correct bucket and then `equals` is consulted to distinguish between different objects with the same hashCode, as the latter is not guaranteed to be unique. In almost any cases this is an extremely bad idea to modify object which serves as a key in a `HashMap` or is put into a `HashSet`. If those modifications change either hashCode or semantics of `equals` method, your object will not be found.

Answer (score 2):

This is by-design behavior.

`HashSet` uses hashes to identify objects it holds.

So, if you change an object after it was placed into collection, it may be unable to find it.

You should either hold immutable objects only, or make mutable only that part of an object, which is not affect the hash.

I think better is to use `HashMap`, which clearly separates mutable and immutable parts.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite clear, you are changing `toInsert.v1` after adding to the set, and due to `DemoClass` obtain hashCode from `v1` and `v2` attributes, it won't find changed hashCode for elementes.